# Configuring Count.ly emails

Tags: countly-analytics

I've just set up Count.ly (Community Edition, v20.11.1 on AWS EC2 instance), and I have a domain name configured with SSL (that's how I'm accessing the Count.ly dashboard).

However, when I create new users, the email that gets sent out to notify users (and for them to set up a password), is using http and the IP address (eg http://123.12.12.12), instead of using the domain name and ssl (ie https://mycountly.example.com).

How can I change the config so that the domain name is used in the emails? I haven;t found anything in the countly dashboard settings, so am presuming there is a config file somewhere in the code that I need to update?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found it now, it was in the server dashboard, under  Management → Settings → API → Server URL

Guess I didn't expect it to be under the API section.